# Is there any vue plugin like movie closing credit?

Tags: vue.js

I need to infinite scroll plugin in my project.

It is NOT **infinite scroll loading**.

I want to make it like a **movie closing credit** and **infinity loop**.

Is there any plugin like this?

Comment: `css: { overflow: scroll }` - you dont need a plugin - it's CSS...

Comment: @DenisTsoi Thanks to reply, but i need **Infinity loop** and animation.

Comment: you need more details in the post btw - 

explain what you're trying to achieve - or give a minimum representation of what it could be...